# String.replace() in python not working for this case

Tags: python, replace

The highlight_word function changes the given word in a sentence to its upper-case version. For example, highlight_word("Have a nice day", "nice") returns "Have a NICE day".
so this is how I created the function but it is not working:

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):
  return(sentence.replace(word,word.upper())


print(highlight_word("Have a nice day", "nice"))
```

It is giving the following error:

```
 File "main.py", line 7
    print(highlight_word("Have a nice day", "nice"))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please help me why is it not working ?

Thankyou

Comment: `return (sentence.replace(word,word.upper())` has one ending bracket missing. Use `return (sentence.replace(word,word.upper()))` or `return sentence.replace(word,word.upper())`

Comment: Hi @purple_tulip, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is likely to be closed in a little while, as we find that solutions to typo-caused issues aren't all that useful to future visitors. But your question is well formatted and clear, so don't feel like we're judging you or that we don't want you to participate (we also all make typos in our own code). Please do stick around and ask any other questions you have later on! You might also want to take the [tour] to learn more about the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the return statement you've given in the syntax:

```
return (sentence.replace(word, word.upper()) ---> ()))
```

Simply a syntax error.

Comment: It's better to just comment if the error was due to a syntactic bug only.